# Story about a girl whose thoughts magically happen

Tags: story-identification, books

I just started to search for a series of books I read about 10 years ago. I read it in French, but don't know if it was from a French author.

It tells the story of a girl (and probably her friend, not sure if it's this story or another one) who can magically make things become real just by thinking them.

They go on an adventure in another world where those "wizards" are known and powerful.

The friend is named something like "Sasha" and becomes some kind of thief in a brotherhood (again, I hope I don't mix another story...)

I particularly remember a moment at the beginning of the first book where the girl is sitting and drawing, and she makes some bullies fall off a bench just by unconsciously thinking about it.

I have tried various searches but my keywords are too generic or already mean something e.g. "making things happens just by thinking about it".

Comment: I have to wonder if you are perhaps thinking of the Changewinds series, by Jack L. Chalker.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I just looked at it and don't really think this is it. I also couldn't find any French version, which is what I read. I'll edit my question.

Comment: That bit about a French version is definitely something you should include; additional information that might be useful would be (a) cover illustration descriptions/style, if you remember; (b) was the writing style familiar (did you recognize it as being similar to a different story that you can name?); (c) was it a translation, or an original work in French (if you remember)... Basically, the more information you can provide, the better.

Comment: Makes me think of the comic [Minus](https://web.archive.org/web/20060415152528/http://www.kiwisbybeat.com:80/minus1.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There it is! I went doing something else and it hit me just like that.

It is a French story named "*La Quête d'Ewilan*", written by Pierre Bottero.

[image: Books cover]

Though, it doesn't seem to exist in English.

Comment: Please edit the Title/Author/Series into your answer as text so that this answer is still helpful for others if the image ever breaks. Thanks.

Comment: It could also be [Les Mondes d'Ewilan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mondes_d%27Ewilan) (sequel) or [Le Pacte des Marchombres](Le Pacte des Marchombres) (prequel I think)

Answer (score 16):

Makes me think of the [*Ewilan* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/56703-la-qu-te-d-ewilan), by French author Pierre Bottero (2003).

[image: books' covers]

**It tells the story of a girl (and probably her friend, not sure if it's this story or another one) who can magically make things become real just by thinking them. They go on an adventure in another world where those "wizards" are known and powerful.**

The main character, Camille, is able to "Draw" (that's the in-universe name of her powers) what she thinks about. She does go to a parallel world where Draughtsmen are indeed common. Most people can make some Drawings, but then again some others are very, very powerful. Unfortunately,

> the ability to Draw was blocked by Ts'Liches, a species of mantis-lizards who are the main enemies for some time.

**I particularly remember a moment at the beginning of the first book where the girl is sitting and drawing, and she makes some bullies fall off a bench just by unconsciously thinking about it.**

There is a scene in the beginning of the first book where some guys make comments at her and her male friend, she thinks it'd be funny if these morons were to fall off their bench, and they do.

**The friend is named something like "Sasha" and becomes some kind of thief in a brotherhood.**

Camille's friend is named Salim, and joins the Marchombres' guild. The Marchombres, which roughly translates into Shadewalkers, value freedom more than anything else. They are trained in stealth, martial arts, climbing, and bypassing some of Nature's laws​, such as being able to walk in a river with powerful flow or riding the hazes.

As they value freedom, they don't judge what guild members should do with these abilities, and some of them do steal stuff. In-universe, it's a common misconception that a Marchombre is likely to be a thief: in fact, the very first scene introducing a Marchombre has the two characters seeing market shopkeepers clearing their stalls, due to a fellow merchant having had a product stealthily stolen by a Marchombre.

So yeah, it seems it could be the *Ewilan* series. As of this day the books haven't been translated; the comics were, but they are an *awful* adaptation of that amazing series.